# How to open the default browser in background and get the source code of a web page?

Tags: c++

I'm using Dev-C++ and i'm looking for a mode to open(...or better...i need to load a browser intance in the background) the default browser (Example I.E.) and send a request to get the source code of the page I requested.

Can I do something like this in C++?

Thank you!

P.S. I need this for Windows

Comment: Sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do? If you just want to access the source of a URL why not just download it directly in your app instead of using a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have imagined the wrong solution for your problem. If you want to get the HTML source for a web page, you don't need to somehow do it through the browser. You need to do whatever the browser does to get it.

When you enter an address into a browser, the browser sends a HTTP GET request to the server that hosts the resource you're requesting (often a web page) and the server sends a HTTP response back containing the resource content (often HTML) back.

You want to do the same in your application. You need to send a HTTP request to the server and read the response. A popular library for doing this is [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to send a POST request (i.e. just a simple web request or with parameters passed on the URL (GET), then you could just use [`URLDownloadToFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you don't want to use callbacks etc. and just download the file, you can call it rather simple:

```
URLDownloadToFile(0, "http://myserver/myfile", "C:\\mytempfile", 0, 0);
```

There are also a few other functions provided that will automatically push the downloaded data to a stream rather than a file.

Answer (score -1):

It can't be done in pure C++. You should use native Windows library or other (like [Qt Framework](http://qt-project.org/)) and use it's capabilities of getting and parsing website. In Qt, you'd use [QtWebkit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html).

edit: also if you want only the source code of a page, you can do this without using browser or their engines, you can use [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673.aspx).